# BlueJ Calculator

Tags: java, calculator, bluej

I need to create a calculator that can add, subtract, multiply, divide, absolute value, and round.
This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
    public static int add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
    public static int subtract(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
        public static int multiply(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2;
    }
        public static double divide(double num1, Double num2)
    {
        return num1 / num2;
    }
        public static double absoluteValue(double num1)
    {
        return;
        if (num1 < 0)
        {
            return = num1 * -1; 
        }
        else
        {
            num1;
        }
    }
        public static double round(double num1)
    {
        return;
        if (num1 + 0.5 >= (int) num1 + 1
        {
            int num2 = (int) num1 + 1
            return = num2;
        }
        else
        {
            return = (int) num1
        }    
    }
}
```

It will not compile correctly, and I do not know if it will function. What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have errors in your code.
In the two last functions, the first line returns immediately, when it should return a double or an int (you were also missing some parenthesis).
Try this:

```
public static double absoluteValue(double num1)
{
    double res = 0;

    if (num1 < 0) res = -num1; 
    else res = num1;

    return res;
}

public static int round(double num1)
{
    int res = 0;

    if (num1 + 0.5 >= ((int) num1) + 1) res = ((int) num1) + 1;
    else res = ((int) num1);

    return res;
}
```

Note that return is a keyword in Java, not a variable.

You should definitely check out this tutorial : http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-methods.html

Also, your main doesn't call any methods so executing this program will not do anything, you need to add input/output interaction with the terminal if you want to simulate a calculator!

Cheers!

Comment: Just a friendly note, if this answers your question, use the checkmark next to the arrows to accept the answer!

Answer (score -1):

public class calculator {
        private int num1;
        private int num2;
        private int result;

```
    public calculator(int newNum1, int newNum2) {
        num1 = newNum1;
        num2 = newNum2;
    }
    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }
    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }
    public int add(int newNum1, int newNum2) {
        result = newNum1 + newNum2;
        return result;
    }
    public int subtract(int newNum1, int newNum2) {
        result = newNum1 - newNum2;
        return result;
    }
    public int divide(int newNum1, int newNum2){
        result = newNum1 / newNum2;
        return result;
    }    
    public int multiply(int newNum1, int newNum2)    {
        result = newNum1 * newNum2;
        return result;
    }
    public void printResult()    {
        System.out.println("The result is " + result + ".");
    }
}
```